# How can I use multiple wildcards in Typescript module declarations?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript3.0

In my ReactJS project I use the [svg-transform-loader](https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-mixer/tree/master/packages/svg-transform-loader) package in WebPack which updates some colors of my SVGs on the fly.

```
import starOutlineIcon from 'images/star-outline.svg'
import greyStarOutlineIcon from 'images/star-outline.svg?stroke=#888888'
```

This works pretty well and I have been using that for a while.

However I've started typing my code using TypeScript (v3.4.5) and I had to use a custom type for images:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: string
    export default content
}
```

I wanted to do the same thing for the transformed SVG, however the module declaration syntax does not support multiple wildcards:

```
declare module '*.svg?stroke=*' {
    const content: string
    export default content
}
```

However this breaks when I use `tsc`:

```
error TS5061: Pattern '*.svg*' can have at most one '*' character.
```

Any idea on how I could declare those modules?

Comment: Just faced the same issue, have you solved yours?

Comment: Still no luck :-(